# Are inverses of fundamental SI units also physical units?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, si-units, metrology

I know that Hertz (1/s) is a physical unit, but are there physical units for 1/m or 1/kg too?
For example, in the formula for resolvance of a diffraction grating, $\frac{\lambda}{\Delta \lambda} = mN$, $N$ is lines per metre. Therefore, its unit should be 1/m, but is it an actual physical unit?

Comment: What does "actual physical unit" mean?

Comment: I meant commonly used units.

Answer (score 2):

"its unit should be 1/m, but is it an actual physical unit?" Yes. It's usually written as $\text m^{-1}$. Whereas, in the SI system, m is a *base* unit, $\text m^{-1}$ is a *derived* unit.

Sometimes derived units are given their own special names according to context. For example, $\text s^{-1}$ is called hertz (Hz) for regularly repeating events, but becquerel (Bq) for (random) radioactive decays. Another example is newton metre (Nm). This is usually called joule (J) when it is used as a unit of work or energy, but *must never be* when used as a unit of torque or moment. [This convention is to reflect the quite different geometric relationship between the force and displacement in the two cases.]

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as an actual physical unit. Even mass doesn’t “really” exist.

https://youtu.be/gSKzgpt4HBU

So 1/kg is certainly ontologically meaningless, and is meaningful only as a tool.

Comment: "Even mass doesn’t “really” exist". By what criterion?

Comment: The video in the comment

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very nice video, mainly about time dilation. I don't see how it supports the non-existence of mass, but perhaps I need to look at the preceding video.

Comment: I may have sent the wrong one. I’ll check in a bit. If so pardon me

Comment: Oh that was it actually. Some comment in maybe 730 or 8 where said “mass is an emergent property arising from “ massless particles interacting.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I did register that comment, but I wouldn't have concluded from it that mass doesn't really exist. I think that in general decisions about whether or not physical concepts like mass or energy actually exist cannot be made within Physics – if indeed at all. Best wishes.

Comment: Yeah.  ||  Thanks you too